# Could neutrino oscillations be due to exchange of gamma rays?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gravity, neutrinos

I was wondering since the relativistic mass-energy of a gamma ray photon is 1.24 MeV/c^2 and the mass of an electron neutrino is < 2.2 eV/c^2 whether the oscillations between the two could, in the case of atmospheric neutrino oscillations be due to electrons (around atomic nuclei) in the atmosphere exchanging gamma ray photons with the neutrinos, yielding a muon neutrino <1.7 MeV/c^2. Not sure how this would work in space, but it seems like the only neutrinos we detect here on Earth have passed through the atmosphere. Could a gamma ray photon enter some sort of superposition with a neutrino? Do you think this explanation could possibly work, or is it just wrong?

Thanks in advance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_neutrino
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum

Comment: Are you perchance casually ignoring the factor of a million encoded by that M?

Comment: You can't say the mass of the electron neutrino is XXX. We don't know its mass at all. We only have a loose conservative upper bound, which is actually 2 eV according to [PDG 2016](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/tables/contents_tables.html) (this is a review updated periodically, listing the best estimates for everything particle physics). As for the 1.24 MeV for "another neutrino", we still don't know where you got that from. The current estimates are 0.19 MeV for the neutrino mu and 18.2 MeV for the neutrino tau (again upper bounds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neutrino oscillations are the [basic explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Solar_neutrino_oscillation) of the solar neutrino problem, i.e. fewer electron neutrinos than the solar model predicted. There are few to  zero electrons in space (~ 1 [hydrogen atom](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/DaWeiCai.shtml) per cubic centimeter for example), and the [neutrino flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino#Observed_data) is 7x10^10 particles·cm^−2·s^ −1, so any neutrino interaction model is out.

Your model is wrong anyway because neutrinos interact with the electric or magnetic field only at higher orders , and this makes the interaction very improbable, on top of the weakness of the weak interaction at first order.

The present  [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) is consistent with all experimental data.

Comment: Also, there are electrons in space...https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/nasa-mission-uncovers-dance-of-electrons-in-space/

Comment: Yes, but not to match the number of neutrios from the sun https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino#Observed_data

Comment: fair point, well made

Answer (score 3):

Predictably, anna has beaten me to it: the interaction between photons and neutrinos is extremely weak. Just for illustration, here are the simplest Feynman diagrams, from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0012257.pdf).

[image]

The diagram (a), for example, has two vertices $\gamma e e$, which already makes it about 100 times smaller than a $\gamma e$ scattering. Then we have two vertices with the $W$ boson, one of the vector of the weak interaction, and that brings even more dramatic a reduction (it is called weak for a reason!). The aforementioned paper computes the following total cross-section from these diagrams.

$$\sigma_{\gamma \nu \to \gamma \nu} = 6.7\times10^{-33}\left(\frac{E_\gamma}{m_e}\right)^6 \text{pb}$$

which is several dozen orders of magnitude smaller than photon-electron cross sections.

Comment: Sorry, got the wrong neutrino, all corrected now :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, got it. I split my answer into a comment and a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

A gamma ray is just a fancy name for one kind of electromagnetic radiation. However, neutrinos are electrically neutral, so they don't "feel" the electromagnetic interaction, only the weak interaction. This is why a neutrino can never directly emit (and also absorb or exchange) electromagnetic radiation like, for example, electrons can (bremsstrahlung).

Comment: But if they're in a superposition with a gamma ray, a classical superposition perhaps instead of quantum, wouldn't it be possible for detectors to read < 1.7 MeV/c^2 in this case making these superposed particle indistinguishable from muon neutrinos?

Comment: If a neutrino is at the same space-time point as a photon (the particle carrying the gamma ray radiation), they won't take any notice of each other.